# Advice needed with mysql query in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following two models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :room
 end


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users
end
```

I want my query to return rooms including users that match my search keyword. It should only return the rooms that have at least one user matching my search keyword.

Right now I have this query:

```
users= User.where do name.matches("%#{params[:name]}%")
```

But it returns a list of users, I want that list to be sorted by room.

Example :

```
Rooms:
[
0: 
{
  name: room1
  users: {# list of users that belong to room 1 and match my search keyword } 
}, 

1: 
{
  name: room2
  users: {# list of users that belong to room 2 and match my search keyword } 
} 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@users = User.joins(:room).where("users.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%").order("rooms.name asc")
```